# Write to file with sed command

Tags: bash, curl, sed

Everyone!!
I want to write result into file with help of sed command:

```
 curl -d "token=%token%" -L "http://storage.dm.com/?cmd=get_props&url=/&" | sed 's/.*"id":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/' > my_root_id
```

And i got the strange result, that :

```
  sed: can't read >: No such file or directorySpentsed: can't read my_root_id: No such file or directory<br>
```

How can i write the result from sed to file?

Comment: What is output of `curl -d "token=%token%" -L "http://storage.dm.com/?cmd=get_props&url=/&"` command?

Comment: @anuhava The output has parameters from server:
             {"response":{"file":{"chksum":"5337905d59b7f5e091291311d796741f","id":"1302400dev1","mtime":1405240829,"name":"outputDemoDocx.xml","sha256"
"2fc7fc3c2f0dcf957973686dd61990978236e9a50144de5759f484faa307592c","size":264628,"type":"application/document","
version_id":"1302500dev1"},"success":"true"},"success":"true"}Done

Comment: does it produces the output when you run `curl -d "token=%token%" -L "http://storage.dm.com/?cmd=get_props&url=/&" | sed 's/.*"id":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'` command?

Comment: What is output of `echo 'abc "id":"123" 999' | sed 's/.*"id":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'` in your shell?

Comment: @Avinash Raj Yes.It produces output : 1302400de‌​v1 . But when i try to write it to file. This file can't be found, what is the nonsense?

Comment: @anubhava it shows me 123

Comment: create a `my_root_id` file on the current directory and put `>>` symbol in your command instead of `>`

Comment: Can you do `touch my_root_id`?

Comment: You're not running that in a shell are you?

Comment: @konsolebox Yes, i launch it in mingw in Windows

Comment: @anubhava i can't do it, because there isn't such command in Mingw

Comment: @Avinash Raj  As i knew, my script actually worked, but with such strange output, that file isn't found. I suppose that it is because of Mingw

Comment: @BilowYuriy Wrap it on a shell script then run that script instead. e.g. `bash script.sh`

Comment: @Nick my script works, but i have warning sed: can't read >: No such file or directory

Comment: Hi. Konsolebox has spotted the problem. The mingw interpreter is not interpreting the > as a redirect of standard out to the file but is instead passing it to sed which is then trying to open the file called >. Run it as a bash script and the redirect will work. Also I think you need to prefix the sed substitution argument with -e